# How to display keyboard key combinations using LaTeX?

Tags: packages

I have this document and I would like to have a similar way to represent keys in my document. What I mean is to have them as small rectangles just like in the picture below.
Is there a LaTeX package that allow me to do that?

[image]

Comment: https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/menukeys/menukeys.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Just as David's comment already pointed out, you can use `menukeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\begin{document}
The date can be set with \keys{\ctrl + c} \keys{\ctrl + s}.

Setting a deadline is done with \keys{\ctrl + c} \keys{\ctrl + d}.

to use the keyboard you can use the \keys{\shift} key plus one of
\keys{\arrowkey{^}}, \keys{\arrowkey{v}}, \keys{\arrowkey{<}} or
\keys{\arrowkey{>}} to navigate inside the calendar view.
\end{document}
```

[image]